# What is a good method for combining several animated gifs onto a single palette?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, adobe-after-effects

I think that what I'm trying to do is simple. I want to take several animated sprites (.gifs) and have them on a single palette (image or video). My ultimate goal is to have it as the background of a div on a website.

Currently, going about this in Photoshop seems a bit clunky and cumbersome. However, I am subscribed to the [Adobe CC](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html) and have access to all other apps. Would After Effects be a better option? or are there better tools for this?

Edit: To clarify my question. I want the gifs layered on top of each other so that it looks like they are all on the same level.

Comment: Please clarify: "layered on top of each other" means they occupy the same area. Do you want that or should the gifs be arranged in rows, columns, or a grid? Have you tried After Effects or Premiere?

Comment: I definitely feel like you need to whip out some sort of example image or try to edit the question as a whole removing the previous explanations. I understand so far that you want to form some sort of image with multiple gifs, but that's not really enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research on my own, I was able to achieve what I wanted to.

What I was trying to achieve was to have several small animated sprites on one single .gif image. So there is a background, in which I wanted to place all of the animated sprites on and have them and have them all animating at the same time. Ultimately, I was able to do this buy importing all the animated sprites into Adobe After Effects and looping them all in a 1.5 second time-span. After Effect gives you the ability to time stretch animated .gif files, this allowed me to keep all of the animations on the screen through the loop without any of them disappearing and reappearing.

After that, I simply exported the animations as a 1.5 second .mov video file. I imported that into Photoshop and broke it into frames. And then I exported that as a .gif file.

Here is the website I used the gifs for: http://www.theothernotch.com

Answer (score 1):

There is some missing information in your question:

**Type of combination:**

One after another?

[image: One after another]

One on top of another?

[image: One on top of another]

Side by side?

[image: Side by side]

On a grid?

[image: grid]

For the three last options it is necessary that these gifs have:

- The same duration or frames number
- The same size

Having this information done, Photoshop is a very simple tool to make this job.

There are also online tools like [Ezgif](https://ezgif.com/help/merging-gifs).